# Change mui-x TimeClock component css style

Tags: mui-x

how can I change the blue color of the MUI TimeClock component indicator to any other color?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9fY1.png)

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { TimeClock } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/TimeClock';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <TimeClock  sx={{"&.MuiTimeClock-root":{},"&.MuiTimeClock-arrowSwitcher":{border:'solid', borderWidth:2}}} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I tried to change the default style through sx but I can't do it.